# In Windows Search, is there a metadata property for permissions or ACL that can be searched on?

Tags: permissions, search, metadata, windows-search, ownership

Basically, I want to be able to search for folders a specific user or security group has access to using Windows Search, but I'm unsure if there is such a metadata attribute that can be used, e.g. permissions:[user] (which, obviously, doesn't work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst this is not exactly 'searching' for ACLs there are ways of displaying this information. One option would be to use [DumpSec](http://www.systemtools.com/somarsoft/index.html) from Somasoft.

Another would be to write a batch file calling the internal Windows command 'Cacls':

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-1050976.html

Or alternatively create a script in Powershell for the same purpose:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/04/15/how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-determine-the-owner-of-a-file.aspx

http://powershellcommunity.org/Forums/tabid/54/aff/14/aft/2724/afv/topic/Default.aspx

Comment: Got what I needed using the Get-Acls command in Powershell, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Now Windows 8 has the ICACLS command: ICACLS name /findsid Sid [/T] [/C] [/L] [/Q]
    finds all matching names that contain an ACL
    explicitly mentioning Sid.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only list a directory and find out it's attributes that way.